# Dynamics using JFugue

Tags: audio-player, jfugue

I have been working with [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/) to generate music.

Does anybody know how to add dynamics to music strings? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as dynamics, but you can include Attack and Decay values on a note.

Here's a Middle-C note, quarter duration, with the implied default values of attack=64 (out of 128) and decay=64 (out of 128): "C5q"

Here's the same note with attack=120 and decay=20: "C5qA120D20"

Comment: You said that you were not sure whether “attacks” and “decays” counted as dynamics. I think that they do, though. Changing "attacks" and "decays" changes articulation, and articulation is a subsection of dynamics. Thank you for your helpful response. (It’s really cool to get a question answered by the developer of the API that you are using!)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I think that I figured it out.

You can change the volume with statements such as `"X[Volume]=10200"` (out of 16383).